# How to convert List<Object> to array of inherited classes?

Tags: c#, arrays, types

```
public Array ListToArray(List<Object> list)
{
   //for example i need convert list to string[] (not knowing that objects is strings)
}
```

I have a list of objects.
All objects of the same type.
But for me the type is not known.
The type can be for example a String, or any other class.
I need to convert this List to the array of inherited classes.
How can I do?

Comment: How do you know what type to cast to? Do you have a `Type` instance? Or a generic type parameter `T`?

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2869110/2132796) answer. Even if you can check the type of objects, it would be better to use a generic method here.

Comment: even if you could do this, how would your work with your array, you would have no idea what type it is. It would become useless?

Comment: @Liam
it is necessary for the DragDrop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Array.CreateInstance` to create an array of the desired type at runtime and then fill it using `Array.Copy`, e.g.:

```
public Array ListToArray(List<Object> list)
{
    // assume there is at least one element in list
    Array arr = Array.CreateInstance(list[0].GetType(), list.Count);
    Array.Copy(list.ToArray(), arr, list.Count);
    return arr;
}
```

Now `ListToArray(new List<object>{1,2})` will return an `int[]` and `ListToArray(new List<object>{"1","2"})` will return a `string[]` (obviously typed as `Array`).

Answer (score 1):

You might want this

```
var result = list.Cast<Object>().ToArray();
```

or for generic type parameter, you can use

```
var result = list.Cast<T>().ToArray();
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `Cast<object>` on an instance of `List<object>`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Type` instance (known at runtime), then you can't cast it, and there's actually no point in doing so. You'll have to use reflection.

If you have a generic type parameter `T`, then you can cast it like this:

```
public class Something<T>
{
    public void ListToArray(List<Object> list)
    {
       var instances = list.Cast<T>().ToArray();
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to *filter* the list's content and obtain those who actually are instances of type `T`, use this instead:

```
var instances = list.OfType<T>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example this should work (if it's a string)

```
var stringArray = list.Select(x=>x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

you can do other casting in select like:

```
var stringArray = list.Select(x=> x as yourType).ToArray();
```

using `as` you will cast object to type you want and it will return null if cast is not possible

Comment: The type can be **for example** a String, **or any other class**

Comment: @Liam so it's for an example

Comment: Note: **not knowing that objects is strings**

Comment: @SriramSakthivel so using `as` you will call `ToString` on object and if it is `string` it will return it's value

Comment: @wudzik You don't understand the question. If List is double OP needs to convert to `List<double>` is what I understand.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel ok, so I'll edit my answer to match this requirement ;)